# Do nested integrals exist?

Tags: integration

I have a problem that involves evaluating (or at lest simplifying) the expression

$$\int_{0}^{x}\int_0^{x'}f(y)dy dx'.$$

Playing around with Riemann sums has lead me to believe that this is just $\int_0^x f(x)dx$ which does not make much sense to me.

Does that expression have a simpler form? Is is even meaningful (i.e., can I do that)?

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, this question is year old... I'm surprised it hasn't had more answers :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under mild hypotheses on $f$ this is a case of Fubini's theorem. Consider the triangle
$$T:=\{(t,y)\>|\>0\leq t\leq x, \ 0\leq y\leq t\}$$
in the $(t,y)$-plane **(draw a figure!)**. Then
$$\int_0^x\int_0^t f(y)\>dy\>dt=\int_T f(y)\>{\rm d}(t,y)=\int_0^x\int_y^x f(y)\>dt\>dy=\int_0^x f(y)(x-y)\>dy\ .$$

Comment: Which agrees perfectly with my answer :D

Answer (score 3):

By the [Cauchy's repeated integral formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration):

$$\int_a^{x_1}\int_a^{x_2}\int_a^{x_3}\dots\int_a^{x_n}f(t)\ dt\ dx_n\dots\ dx_3\ dx_2\ dx_1=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_a^{x_1}f(t)(x_1-t)^{n-1}\ dt$$

which I find analogous to the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) from complex analysis for $n$th derivatives (instead of integrals):

$$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma f(s)(s-z)^{-n-1}\ ds$$

where pretty much everything gets flipped upside down.

In the event of $a=0$ and $n=2$, we get

> $$\int_0^{x_1}\int_0^{x_2}f(t)\ dt\ dx_2=\int_0^{x_1}f(t)(x_1-t)\ dt$$

Comment: D: Could someone explain why the downvotes?

Comment: You have not answered the question. To OP (or anyone on similar level), this will be incomprehensible or confusing, and to anyone else, it will probably be irrelevant.

Comment: Besides, the formula you have cited is not anywhere in the article you have cited, not even implicitly as far as I can tell. In fact, I don't see how that is even related (I'm not saying it isn't, but you certainly did not show that it is).

Comment: @tomasz D: you are right!  I meant a different but very similar formula, and I've fixed it.  Whether or not this is incomprehensible or not, I thought it was interesting and unique, compared to the other answers, so I thought the addition would be good.

Comment: @tomasz and even as it was earlier, I do not see how it wouldn't have answered the OP's question.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: This answer certainly doesn't have negative value. One of the great things about math.stackexchange is that people can give different answers that provide different perspectives. I learned something from this.

Comment: @littleO Thanks.  And I think what you say is true.  (It is also rather common for me to stumble upon a question that seems like it could use some interesting content, but I have to step outside the box to add that content)

Comment: All the x_n have the same value. Maybe that should be said.

Comment: @mick They do not.  They depend on the next outer integral:$$\int_0^x\int_0^{x'}f(y)\ dy\ dx'\ne\int_0^x\int_0^xf(y)\ dy\ dx$$

Comment: Im confused now

Comment: @mick Notice that $x_n$ is not a constant.  It is a "variable", so how can all the $x_n$ be the same and have the same value?

Comment: @mick As an explanation of how these work:$$\int_0^{x_1}\int_0^{x_2}t\ dt\ dx_2=\int_0^{x_1}\frac12x_2^2\ dx_2=\frac16x_1^3$$Likewise,$$\frac1{1!}\int_0^{x_1}t(x_1-t)\ dt=\dots=\frac16x_1^3$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous, if $F_{1}$ is a primitive of $f$, and if $F_{2}$ is a primitive of $F_{1}$, then
$$
\int_{x'= 0}^{x}\int_{y=0}^{x'}f(y)dydx'= \int_{x'=0}^{x}\left[F_{1}(x') - F_{1}(0)\right]dx' = F_{2}(x) - F_{2}(0) - F_{1}(0)x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Such things exist, but your conclusion is at least a little wrong. For instance, let f(y) = 1. Then

$$\int_0^x \int_0^{x'} 1 dy dx' = \int_0^x x' dx' = x^2/2$$

unless by the primes you intended some sort of differentiation.

Comment: You probably mean $x$ instead of $x'$ in the result :)

Comment: Indeed, that is an error.